# Fill series in R

Tags: r, loops, series, fill

I want to update column 2 so that the the value pairs update to (a,1)(b,1)(c1) and (d,2)(e,2)(f,2) and (g,3)(h,3)(i,3) and so on. How do I loop through?
Here is the sample data frame:

```
data_set <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=9))
data_set$column1_set1 <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i")
data_set$column2_set1 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

data_set <- data_set[,-1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data_set <- data.frame(column1_set1 = letters[1:9], 
                       column2_set1 = rep(1:3, each=3))
```

Answer (score 1):

With the given data set you can use this to update column 2  in pairs: a,1 etc
Paste comma in the set1 and repeat of 1:3 each=3 times!

```
data_set$column2_set1 =paste0(data_set$column1_set1,",",rep(1:3, each=3))
```

===
You could have used mutate as well with dplyr :

```
data_set%>%
  mutate("column2_set1" = paste0(column1_set1,",",rep(1:3, each=3)))
```

output : 

  `column1_set1 column2_set1
1            a          a,1
2            b          b,1
3            c          c,1
4            d          d,2
5            e          e,2
6            f          f,2
7            g          g,3
8            h          h,3
9            i          i,3`